# How can you set the customer group pricing for specific logged in ids as 50 percent discount for all products in magento2?

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules, special-price, price-rules

How can we enable the customer group pricing for a specific set of the customers and even reflect that price while adding items to cart as well from Magento storefront screen?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `catalog price rule` and select the `customer group` who will be eligible for the discount.
[image: customer group]

In `conditions` tab you can select the condition for which product this discount will be applied.
[image: conditions]